# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед "что", если в предложении присутствует деепричастие?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастия

Она не пошла сегодня в школу, думая(,) что сегодня праздничный день.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: ***Она не пошла в шкОлу, думая, что сегодня праздничный дЕнь.***

В устной речи в  малораспространенных предложениях пауза перед союзом ЧТО может отсутствовать, но запятая ставится по обычным правилам – после деепричастия перед придаточным предложением.

В более распространенных предложениях пауза  слышится в большей степени;

*Маргарита покорно вЫпила, **дУмая, что** тут же ей и будет конец от спИрта.* [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 2 (1929-1940)]

Comment: «Думая» — не деепричастие, а часть деепричастного оборота с изъяснительным придаточным, так как если и несет самостоятельную смысловую нагрузку, то не ту, которая нужна автору.

Comment: Любопытный случай, так как ударение приходится на придаточное внутри деепричастного оборота.